# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. But I can't find nill value in my statement

Tags: swift

I've got an error on the `let myValue` line:

```
@IBAction func CAttamaran(_ sender: Any) {

    // error happens here
    let myValue:NSString = (sender as AnyObject).titleLabel!!.text! as NSString

    UserDefaults.standard.set(myValue, forKey:"Shared room")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    if let myOutput2: AnyObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Shared room") as AnyObject? {
        // self.appDelegate.propertylabel = "\(myOutput2)" as NSString!
        let secondViewController1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "propertyvc")
        self.present(secondViewController1, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("property_id = \(myOutput2)")    
    }
}
```

Comment: On what line are you getting the exception? I see you have multiple forced unwraps(`!`), that can possibly be the reason why you're receiving the null reference exception.

Comment: Any exclamation mark can cause that exception. In the first line you have already 3 (!) possible crash reasons. And replace those `as AnyObject` bridge casts with a down cast to the actual type. And don't use `NSString` in Swift.

Comment: Don't force unwrap. Don't force unwrap twice or thrice!! And don't use `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()`. Also don't declare the variable type if the compiler can find it itself. Last, you should avoid converting to NSString when you can use String instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any exclamation mark can cause that exception.

in your case

> // problematic line is
>
> let myValue:NSString = (sender as AnyObject).titleLabel!!.text! as
>   NSString

as we can see there is multiple chance of getting nil value 
like

1. sender may not be castable as AnyObject
2. titleLabel might be nil
       especially if sender is an Objective-C object that doesn't have a
       titleLabel property.
3. titleLabel.text might be nil.

Solution for this is use guard statement like below

```
  @IBAction func CAttamaran(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard let myValue = sender.titleLabel?.text else {
        // Handle the edge case here
        return
    }


    guard let storyboard = self.storyboard else {
        // Handle the edge case here
        return
    }
    // Rest of code
}
```

Comment: You should put some explanation in, not just post a line of raw code.

Comment: This answer still has some risks to crash when force unwrapping the `sender` so I would say it is a poor answer. The other thing is that it just answers the exact question, but doesn't bring knowledge improvements to the author.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
let myValue:NSString = (sender as AnyObject).titleLabel!!.text! as NSString
```

has three unwrappings in it, any one of which could be your problem

- `sender` may not be castable as `AnyObject`
- `titleLabel` might be `nil` especially if `sender` is an Objective-C object that doesn't have a `titleLabel` property.
- `titleLabel.text` might be `nil`.

If you want to find out what the problem is, you need to do the unwrappings one at a time e.g.

```
guard let sender = sender as WhateverTypeYouThinkItShouldBe else { fatalError("sender is the wrong type") }
guard let titleLabel = sender.titleLabel else { fatalError("Title label is nil") }
if let text = titleLabel.text
{
     // Do whatever you need to do
}
else
{
     // There is no text in the label
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line of code you are pointing on, has a lot of issues:

```
let myValue:NSString = (sender as AnyObject).titleLabel!!.text! as NSString
```

1. First and first, force unwrapping like that is evil. It's the biggest source for possible crashes.
2. Why do you try to cast to `AnyObject`? That one doesn't have `titleLabel` property, so this wrong.
3. Why do you cast the `text` to `NSString`? Didn't notice any particular `NSString` API usage.

   if let myOutput2: AnyObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Shared room") as AnyObject? {
4. You read again the same value from `UserDefaults` that you just saved. 
   If you rewrite your code in more Swift friendly way, it would be better:

Here is an example of your re-written function:

```
@IBAction func CAttamaran(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard let myValue = sender.titleLabel?.text else {
        // Handle the edge case here
        return
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(myValue, forKey:"Shared room")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    guard let storyboard = self.storyboard else {
        // Handle the edge case here
        return
    }
    let secondViewController1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "propertyvc")
    self.present(secondViewController1, animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("property_id = \(myValue)")
}
```

Comment: Also, why not just have sender being `UIButton`? Clearly this @IBAction does nothing unless sender is `UIButton`, so why allow attaching it to any other type.